# Java - Authenticate user using web application's security framework without Http requests

Tags: java, authentication, web-applications, rmi

So I have a Tomcat server within a Java web application, authentication is done using Tomcat's usernames and passwords specified in the *tomcat-users.xml* file, and form based authentication (posting to *j_security_check*). I have now also registered a remote object (using Java RMI) that I want to access from outside of the web context, from an eclipse plugin.

My intention is to obtain the remote object which has a method

```
public AnotherRemoteClsWithRestrictedMethods login(user, pass);
```

and then the implementation uses the web application's security framework to verify the user and password combination. If valid, would then return another object with restricted methods.

How would I go about obtaining / querying the web application's security details?

Note: I do not have an `HttpRequest` object, should I call another URL to verfiy the user? Any other ways?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`j_security_check` is a HTTP based authentication. You'll really need to fire a HTTP request.
You can use [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) for this, or the more convenienced [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

Comment: Yeah I figured that's one way but ideally I don't want to have to fire an HTTP request, is there no static method like SecurityContext.verifyUser(user, pass)?

Comment: Not in Servlet API, no. You'll need to parse the `tomcat-users.xml` yourself and grab/test the credentials. Better is to store them in a database and let Tomcat use a `DatasourceRealm` (or `JDBCRealm`) instead. This way you can more easy access the credentials from other sources.